# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a dataset on a dynamodb table and i have a script to populate this table. Locally i can interact with it using

```
const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'myProfile'})
```

But then i have the lambda rate function and i when i try to interact with the db with this approach:

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1", // your AWS region
    accessKeyId: 'KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'key/key'
});
```

I got the error from the title:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`

Although the `accessKeyId` and the `secretAccessKey` are the same.

An example of method:

```
const queryTokens = async () => {
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: "brc-20",
    };

    const command = new ScanCommand(params);
    const response = await client.send(command);

    return response.Items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message, 'for queryTokens');
  }
};
```

Comment: When you invoke an AWS Service from a Lambda function, you do not need to specify credentials. Instead, for the Lambda function,  specify a role that has permission to interact with the AWS Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always bad practice to hardcode credentials, both from a security perspective but also because things can go wrong and cause issues like you are witnessing here.

When making calls to AWS services from Lambda, you should use your [Lambda Execution Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) to permit your function with the necessary permissions such as `dynamodb:Scan`.

In your code there is no need to configure access keys, as Lambda will assume the execution role by default.